hide navigationBar in BottomSheetDialogFragment
I have a class that inherits from BottomSheetDialogFragment and has an onCreateDialog function as follows
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val bottomSheetDialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
    binding = FragmentSelectCastDeviceBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(binding.root)
    hideNavigationBarInDialog(bottomSheetDialog)
    initMain()
    return bottomSheetDialog
}


    fun hideNavigationBarInDialog(dialog: Dialog) {
    dialog.window?.let { window ->
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).let { controller ->
            controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior =
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }
}

My problem is that it is hidden, but it still has the width of the navigationBar remaining, how can I remove that width? The part I highlighted in red is the width of the navigationBar after being hidden


I don't think this is possible because System Bars are part of the OS itself and can only be hidden by enabling Edge-to-Edge for immersion.
These bars will always occupy space even when hidden because they provide system information(status bar) and system navigation for switching between apps, home button and back button(navigation bar).
What you can do is make it part of your layout by changing it's color with a theme.
themes.xml
<style name="Theme.BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/your_color</item>
</style>

And in your BottomSheetDialogFragment override getTheme()
override fun getTheme(): Int  = R.style.Theme_BottomSheetDialogTheme

https://developer.android.com/design/ui/mobile/guides/foundations/system-bars
